# Black Screen When Using Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to make a match 3 game. For starters, I wanted to draw something on the screen, but no matter what I try, I get just a black screen.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //MAKE FULLSCREEN
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    GameView gameview = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameview);
   }
}
public class GameView extends SurfaceView{
private int numCol, numRow;
private int bWid, bHeight;
private Bitmap purpleBit;
private Bitmap rainbowBitmp;
private Bitmap redBitmp;

  public GameView(Context context){
    super(context);
  }
  @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 0, 0));
    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, paint);
  }
}
```

Comment: SurfaceView is more difficult to use. Start learning it with this article (http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/311-urok-141-risovanie-dostup-k-canvas.html) (rus)

Comment: Try removing super.ondraw

Answer (score 0):

Set the paint width, color, stroke

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //MAKE FULLSCREEN
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    GameView gameview = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameview);
   }
}
public class GameView extends SurfaceView{
private int numCol, numRow;
private int bWid, bHeight;
private Bitmap purpleBit;
private Bitmap rainbowBitmp;
private Bitmap redBitmp;

  public GameView(Context context){
    super(context);
  }
  @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();

   //this is missing
    mPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 0, 0));
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);


    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, mPaint);
  }
}
```

Comment: why `setColor` 2 times?

Comment: optional either use RGB or direct colors